# imageflow animation looks bad on IE with opacity=false

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, animation, imageflow

I've been trying to install imageFlow in a site. It works fine except in IE (8 in mycase).
The problem is that the animation isn't smooth. I've looked at their [demo](http://imageflow.finnrudolph.de/) in IE8 and it works great.
I can't for the life of me understand why my example isn't working and theirs does. I"ve tried changing the options of imageFlow based on the [examples](http://finnrudolph.de/ImageFlow/Examples) but to no avail.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<div id="carousel" class="imageflow" style="border:solid 1px;height:292px;width:971px;background-image:url('images/carousel/carouselBackground.jpg');"> 
<img src="path1.jpg" longdesc="" width="666" height="500" alt="1" />
<img src="path2.jpg" longdesc="" width="666" height="500" alt="2" />
<img src="path3.jpg" longdesc="" width="666" height="500" alt="3" />
<img src="path4.jpg" longdesc="" width="666" height="500" alt="4" />
<img src="path5.jpg" longdesc="" width="666" height="500" alt="5" />
</div>

<script>
domReady(function()
{
var instanceOne = new ImageFlow();
instanceOne.init({ ImageFlowID: 'carousel',
                    reflections: false,
        slider: true,
                    reflectionP: 0.2,
        aspectRatio: 3.32,
        imagesHeight: 0.7,
                    captions: false,
                    opacity: false,
                    xStep: 150,
        buttons: true,
        imageFocusM: 1.0,
                    startID: 3 });
});
</script>
```

When I change opacity to true, the broken animation is fixed for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have exactly the same issue. A workaround I found was to enable opacity, then simply set all images be completely opaque, like so:

```
 opacity: true, opacityArray: [10,10,10,10,10]
```

Comment: That's exactly the workaround I used as well at that time.
Now however I just switched to a something better than image flow (more configurable) - it's called contentflow (http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/)

Comment: That fix worked for me, too. Interesting sidenote: I switched from contentflow to imageflow due to performance issues in IE - contentflow didn't work as smooth as imageflow.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks!
I had that problem to, and your help was absolutely great.
I don't know what version he have in Imageflow homepage in the examples tab but when i go there with IE8 i don't have the same problem.
The issue of having an array with the opacity for the photos, you need to have an array width a length equal to the number of your images?